# Vim add '*' character for docs on new line

Tags: php, vim

I don't even know how to search for this on google, I tried with the title of this question, but could not find anything useful.

Working with PHP on Vim, if I have something like this:

```
/**
 * <cursor>
 */
```

If I press enter, I'll get:

```
/**
 * 
 <cursor>
 */
```

What I want is this:

```
/**
 * 
 * <cursor>
 */
```

Yes, it is just one character, but it is bugging me a little bit.
What is the easiest way to achieve this?

### Edit:

My `.vimrc` file have these commands (and others):

```
" Enable syntax highlight
syntax on
" Syntax in a plugin-based way
filetype on
" Indentation in a plugin-based way
filetype indent plugin on

set fo+=or
```

Comment: @dev-null-dweller that did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, what you need below lines in your vimrc:

```
filetype on
filetype indent plugin on
```

Comment: I already have this. Should've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the configuration of [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) and it works for me. I think that the plugin [PHP Integration environment for Vim - PIV](https://github.com/spf13/PIV) makes the trick because have a feature for documentation
conforming documentation blocks for your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm sorry for this. I found the problem:

```
autocmd FileType php,phtml :set ft=php.html
```

I used this line to load HTML snippets for PHP files with the `snipMate.vim` plugin. Turns out, if I remove this line, the behaviour will be what I expected to be.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: ... ok.. then your question is like `a=3, b=4, why a+b=10?`. and it turns out, you have another line `a=a==3?2*a:a` after `a=3`...

Comment: Well, I did not know where the problem was and nobody would look my 200 lines `.vimrc` file. I tried to comment parts of this file and relauch vim. With some "binary search", I could precisely determine where the problem was. Maybe I should've done this before posting here, but other people may have the same problem.

Comment: It's ok. I was kidding. I don't know if you had a customized status line, (e.g. many people are using the powerline plugin) you could add filetype somewhere on your status line. Then you could see the ft very easily. Back to your question/problem. The first thing one should look is the filetype, (`set ft?`) when I tested with your text, I did `set ft=php`. anyway, you learned it from your question today I think.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not an expert in Vim, so, baby steps =). Probably I'll have to alternate between file types when I'm writing regular PHP files and when I'm writing mixed template files. It is not the best solution, but will work for now.